# Can MD5 values change depending on OS?

Tags: linux, md5

Currently i am trying to install linux

I was just checking md5 checksum to see if the file is downloaded correctly or not.

situation is like this.
I have downloaded linux   .iso file in win xp have checked the md5 from Microsoft 'File checksum integrity verifier' utility. it is giving a different checksum from the one displayed on the linux OS website.

Q. IS the md5 checksum different (or same)  on different OS ( winxp, win7, linux etc) ??

Comment: md5 sums are the same regardless of the OS.

Comment: They are the same -- were I you, I'd redownload the ISO.

Comment: Does “Microsoft 'File checksum integrity verifier' utility” actually give MD5 hashes? I wouldn't be surprised if it didn't.

Comment: It does both MD5 and SHA-1. Are you sure you aren't getting the SHA-1 hash?